# Python - Reading the contents of csv in python and appending it

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, append, tuples

```
 import csv
 with open("somecities.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = [r for r in reader]
```

Contents of somecities.csv:

```
Country,Capital,CountryPop,AreaSqKm

Canada,Ottawa,35151728,9984670

USA,Washington DC,323127513,9833520

Japan,Tokyo,126740000,377972

Luxembourg,Luxembourg City,576249,2586
```

New to python and I'm trying to read and append a csv file. I've spent some time experimenting with some responses to similar questions with no luck--which is why I believe the code above to be pretty useless.

What I am essentially trying to achieve is to store each row from the CSV in memory using a dictionary, with the country names as keys, and values being tuples containing the other information in the table in the sequence they are in within the CSV file.

And from there I am trying to add three more cities to the csv(Country, Capital, CountryPop, AreaSqKm) and view the updated csv. How should I go about doing all of this?

The desired additions to the updated csv are:

Brazil, Brasília, 211224219, 8358140

China, Beijing, 1403500365, 9388211

Belgium, Brussels, 11250000, 30528

EDIT:

```
Import csv
with open("somecities.csv", "r") as csvinput:
    with open(" somecities_update.csv", "w") as csvresult:
        writer = csv.writer(csvresult, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
        all = []
        headers = next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            all.append(row)

        # Now we write to the new file
        writer.write(headers)
        for record in all:
            writer.write(record)


        #row.append(Brazil, Brasília, 211224219, 8358140)
        #row.append(China, Beijing, 1403500365, 9388211)
        #row.append(Belgium, Brussels, 11250000, 30528)
```

Comment: you can explore python pandas that's the best  candidates.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a pandas dataframe? That would probably be the way I would do it if you. Again, maybe there's a reason not to do that way?

Comment: `data = {r[0]: tuple(r[1:]) for r in reader}`? or have I misunderstood? You don't need to use a `DictReader` for that though, you want the regular `csv.reader()`

Comment: @roganjosh I've done what you have suggested but I am now experiencing an AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader'.

Comment: can you add the desired output?

Comment: @TheIllusiveNick have you named your script `csv.py`? If so, rename it

Comment: Well said @roganjosh!

Answer (score 0):

`DictReader` will only represent each row as a dictionary, eg:

```
{
  "Country": "Canada",
  ...,
  "AreaSqKm": "9984670"
}
```

If you want to store the whole CSV as a dictionary you'll have to create your own:

```
import csv

all_data = {}

with open("somecities.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # Key = country, values = tuple containing the rest of the data.
        all_data[row["Country"]] = (row["Capital"], row["CountryPop"], row["AreaSqKm"])

# Add the new cities to the dictionary here...

# To write the data to a new CSV
with open("newcities.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, values in all_data.items():
        writer.writerow([key] + list(values))
```

As others have said, though, the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library could be a good choice. Check out its [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) functions.

Comment: One issue I am running into with the code you have proposed is an AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictReader'. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: Not sure why you're running into that issue. Worst case you can use the standard `csv.reader`, keeping in mind that rows will now be represented as lists. So, in the initial loop, you'd use something like `all_data[row[0]] = tuple(row[1:])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you can use pandas for this I would go about it this way:

```
import pandas as pd   

df1 = pd.read_csv('your_initial_file.csv', index_col='Country')
df2 = pd.read_csv('your_second_file.csv', index_col='Country')

dfs = [df1,df2]

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another idea with creating and list and appending the new values through list construct as below, not tested:

```
import csv
with open("somecities.csv", "r") as csvinput:
    with open("result.csv", "w") as csvresult:
        writer = csv.writer(csvresult, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append(Brazil, Brasília, 211224219, 8358140)
        row.append(China, Beijing, 1403500365, 9388211)
        all.append(row)
        for row in reader:
            row.append(row[0])
            all.append(row)
        writer.writerows(all)
```

**The simplest Form i see, tested in python 3.6**

Opening a file with the 'a' parameter allows you to append to the end of the file instead of simply overwriting the existing content. Try that.

```
>>> with open("somecities.csv", "a") as fd:
...     fd.write("Brazil, Brasília, 211224219, 8358140")
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import csv
fields=['Brazil', 'Brasília', '211224219','8358140']
with open(r'somecities.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: This is becoming more common when trying to use the batches of code suggested: I'm running into an AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer'. Do you have any suggestions to how I should resolve this?

Comment: @TheIllusiveNick, which version of python you are using and what os flavour?
However, may be into your code you have a variable name `csv = something?`
Dont try to use module name as a variable or as a script name this is what the issue most of the time.

Comment: One potential problem could be that I'm also using a python 3.6 interpreter?

Comment: python 3.6 has the writer function, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: @TheIllusiveNick I already made a suggestion in the comments under your question. You did not reply to me.

Comment: @TheIllusiveNick, try the updated append method with python3.6 and it should work.

Comment: @pygo I've been messing with it for some time now and have made some edits that are shown in my post above. Would you say your appended method is still applicable (I tried to implement it with no luck) or is there another approach I should be taking to complete this?

Comment: @TheIllusiveNick, you can try my third solution , thats is working model.